# Converting input Names to Arrays in Keras

Tags: python, keras

I have a CNN model that I am training with named classes.

```
 CATEGORIES = ['HTC-1-M7', 'iPhone-4s', 'iPhone-6', 'LG-Nexus-5x', 
              'Motorola-Droid-Maxx', 'Motorola-Nexus-6', 'Motorola-X', 
              'Samsung-Galaxy-Note3', 'Samsung-Galaxy-S4', 'Sony-NEX-7']
```

Later in the code, I try:

`Y_end=model.predict(CATEGORIES,number_test_samples)`

I do this to help me get a Confusion Matrix based on the code given in https://gist.github.com/RyanAkilos/3808c17f79e77c4117de35aa68447045

But when I try to run the code I get an error saying: 
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'`

I looked up Keras.io about the formatting of parameters for model.predit and read that "A dict mapping input names to the corresponding array/tensors, if the model has named inputs."

I am trying to find information about implementing a dictionary mapping and cannot find anything

Comment: Predict takes only "data", nothing else.

Comment: I tried doing that. When I did predict(trainng_data,categories) I got an error saying expected conv2d_28_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (2, 1). And i get similar errors when I use one of the two.

Comment: You passed an incompatible array. The array should have 4 dimensions but what you passed had shape (2,1). Also, it should be only data, there is no "categories" on predict. If you managed to train, then you can also predict and see the results with the same rules you used for training.